# Syntax error when trying to grab and run code from github

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a page from github to be read and executed with PHP upon page load due to it updating often, although while I've managed to format the page to what should be correct, it still doesn't seem to work.

Basically, I've used the file_get_contents to grab all of the information on the page (if I get this working it should potentially work with any page), removed all comments, and now I just need the code to run.

I've heard eval is unsafe, but it's only a personal website and I trust the github page isn't going to use malicious code, but I'm getting a "syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING", when the page runs, despite the fact I haven't touched the code and it runs fine if copied and pasted.

Here is the code I've used to remove the comments, I can't see any problem on or around line 391 where it says the error is, http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php works if you copy and paste it in

```
#get page data, remove intro comment (unefficient but can be rewritten once working)
$browsercoderaw = explode("*/",file_get_contents("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cbschuld/Browser.php/master/lib/Browser.php"));
for($i==1;$i<count($browsercoderaw);$i++){
    if($i>1){$browsercodejoined.=" */";} # replace */ for other comments so they can be removed later
    $browsercodejoined.=$browsercoderaw[$i];}
$browsercode = nl2br(str_replace("?>","",$browsercodejoined));

#remove all /* comments
$commentremove = explode("/*",$browsercode);
$browsercode2 = $commentremove[0];
for($j==1;$j<count($commentremove);$j++){
    $commentsplit = explode("*/",$commentremove[$j]);
    $browsercode2.=$commentsplit[1];
}

#remove all // comments
$commentremove2 = explode("<br />",$browsercode2);
$browsercode3 = $commentremove2[0];
$linenum = 0;
for($k==1;$k<count($commentremove2);$k++){
    $commentsplit = explode("//",$commentremove2[$k]);
    if(strlen(trim($commentsplit[0]))>0){
        $browsercode3.=$commentsplit[0];
        $browsercodereadable.=$linenum.". ".$commentsplit[0]."<br>";
        $linenum++;
    }
}

echo $browsercodereadable;
eval($browsercode3);
?>
```

Also, if there is a better way of doing this please say so, I tried include but the webhost doesn't allow fetching urls from other domains. To be fair, I'm not entirely sure if it's the correct use of eval, but it sounds like it should potentially work.

Comment: this surely isn't the best way to do this. Either way, what happens if you don't strip out the comments?

Comment: Have you, for instance, [considered using Git](https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php) to grab the files? I would also strongly consider abandoning downloading and running files as you are and work with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) instead.

Comment: That's really strange, I did the comment removal due to it throwing errors at the comments before, but it somehow now works when I revert back to the original code with comments (so - do I delete the question or leave it?). And thanks jared, I'll also look into Git, although I'm on a free webhost so I won't be able to get anything installed